# Mathematica Import functions fails for data download from website

Tags: import, web-access

I am trying to download some data from a website that uses "java enabling" to tell me that I cannot download the data. Using

```
Import[ "website...", "Data"]
```

I get

```
{....."You need Javascript enabled to view live scores. Loading... Loading... ..}
```

Do I have to use something like squid to change requester_id so it shows up as a web-browser rather than Mathematica ?

I have now fixed this problem. The second problem is that Mathematica does not support iframe. Does it ? Is there a way around this issue ?

Comment: Please post your code and the website you are trying to scrape. You should probably post your second question as a separate question.

Comment: You wrote: "I have now fixed this problem."  Please post your solution as an answer to your own question, as soon as the system will allow it (a matter of "reputation" points and time).

Comment: No, my fault, I have not fixed anything. I deluded myself into believing I had fixed this issue. I just tried a different category on the same site which did not work either but gave the iframe error message. Sorry.

Comment: @Verbeia for example, http://www.livexscores.com/livescore/football i am into live quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The user agent (requester_id) probably isn't the issue. Indeed, Mathematica does not appear as a standard browser to web servers (it identifies itself as Mathematica), but that usually isn't an issue for normal HTML pages. And indeed Squid can solve problems if your page is testing for a specific browser (see also an earlier question on [user agents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089926/615464))

For pages that are partly generated by a Javascript script this is different, as Mathematica does not interpret Javascript. I don't think you can get this to work.

Comment: If you are completely crazy, or desperate/curious, you could interface with a javascript interpreter via MathLink, like [FireFox's SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide). I'm almost tempted to do it, myself, and yes I fall under the crazy/curious header.

Comment: would there be other ways to scrape the data ? with ruby or scrapy ?

Comment: @rcollyer for example something like http://www.livexscores.com/livescore/football ? i guess ruby would be the way to go, no ?

Comment: nevermind i am closing this question.

Comment: I am very curious about updates here, I have mathematica 9 and also cant doload a page because of either iframe  or because mathematica identifies as Mathematica not as say Chrome. any updates?

Comment: @AimForClarity As mentioned above, Squid can change the user agent name. Also, please follow the link in my answer above where you can find information about CNTLM. Another option would be [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). No solutions for pages that are dynamically updated based on the execution of javascript scripts.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thanks SjoerdC

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is reading this Q&A in 2018 or later, the situation is a bit different because there is now a Chrome driver that can be used to evaluate JavaScript. It is still experimental at the time of writing. Please look for more recent Q&As such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182419/731) or even more recent.